# Adding geom_segment to faceted plot that have free x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a faceted plot with a free x axis (`scales = "free_x"`). The x axis is a categorical variable and I am having problems aligning a geom_segment. Is there an easy way to avoid the issue presented in the following example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(HistData)
library(datasets)

data(Cholera)

Cholera

stats <- Cholera %>% group_by(region, water) %>% summarise(mean = mean(cholera_drate), max = max(cholera_drate))

# This works but I want to get rid of empty categories
ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(data = Cholera, aes(x = region, y = cholera_drate)) +
  geom_point(data = stats, aes(x = region, y = mean), color = "red") +
  geom_segment(data = stats, aes(x = as.numeric(region) - 0.25, xend = as.numeric(region) + 0.25, y = mean, yend = mean), color = "blue") +
  facet_wrap(~ water)

# If I use free_x then geom does not align anymore
ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(data = Cholera, aes(x = region, y = cholera_drate)) +
  geom_point(data = stats, aes(x = region, y = mean), color = "red") +
  geom_segment(data = stats, aes(x = as.numeric(region) - 0.25, xend = as.numeric(region) + 0.25, y = mean, yend = mean), color = "blue") +
  facet_wrap(~ water, scales = "free_x")
```

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to do is to use `facet_grid` with `scales = free_x`  and then `space = free_x` to get:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(data = Cholera, aes(x = region, y = cholera_drate)) +
  geom_point(data = stats, aes(x = region, y = mean), color = "red") +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(water), scales = "free_x", space = "free_x") +
  geom_segment(data = stats,
           aes(x = as.numeric(region) - 0.25, xend = as.numeric(region) + 0.25,
               y = mean, yend = mean), color = "blue")
```

Then you'll see that the real problem is the fact that you're positioning the segment based on the numeric factor of `region` which changes when you use `space = free_x` & `scales = free_x` thereby leaving the segment behind in the first facet as seen below:

[image]

The only thing I can think of to solve this is a sort of a hack. We'll create a separate data for the segments from `stats` and then change the 'Kent' value to 'North' which is the desired position (of the segment left behind) after we do `space = free_x` & `scales = free_x` as seen below:

```
data_lab <- stats
data_lab$region[8] <- "North"  ## change Kent to North

ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(data = Cholera, aes(x = region, y = cholera_drate)) +
  geom_point(data = stats, aes(x = region, y = mean), color = "red") +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(water), scales = "free_x", space = "free_x") +
  geom_segment(data = data_lab,
  aes(x = as.numeric(region) - 0.25, xend = as.numeric(region) + 0.25,
               y = mean, yend = mean), color = "blue")
```

to get:

[image]

I hope it helps.